# XSL conditional sum

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to transform an xml. The old xsl was written by someone else and it is quite static, looks for every node and writes them. But I need to change it to dynamic way. Here is the xml file (simplified version):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <csprint>
  <csrequest>
   <p:Body xmlns:p="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v1="wsdl.http://isbank.com/OpSvcs/PaymentMgmtProcessing/TaxCollection/Service/V1" xmlns:v1_1="http://isbank.com/OpSvcs/PaymentMgmtProcessing/TaxCollection/Service/V1" xmlns:v1_2="http://isbank.com/OpSvcs/PaymentMgmtProcessing/Tax/Schema/V1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
     <v1_1:collect>
      <v1_1:collectionData>
       <v1_2:taxOfficeNo>34256</v1_2:taxOfficeNo>
       <v1_2:mainTaxCode>9077</v1_2:mainTaxCode>
       <v1_2:debtLineItem>
        <v1_2:taxCode>1086</v1_2:taxCode>
        <v1_2:installmentNumber>1</v1_2:installmentNumber>
        <v1_2:dueDate>2011-02-28</v1_2:dueDate>
        <v1_2:amount>
         <amount>174134.40</amount>
        </v1_2:amount>
        <v1_2:taxShortName>Y.DIŞI ÇKŞ.H</v1_2:taxShortName>
       </v1_2:debtLineItem>
       <v1_2:debtLineItem>
        <v1_2:taxCode>1086</v1_2:taxCode>
        <v1_2:installmentNumber>1</v1_2:installmentNumber>
        <v1_2:dueDate>2011-02-28</v1_2:dueDate>
        <v1_2:amount>
          <amount>174134.40</amount>
        </v1_2:amount>
        <v1_2:taxShortName>Y.DIŞI ÇKŞ.H</v1_2:taxShortName>
      </v1_2:debtLineItem>
      <v1_2:debtLineItem>
        <v1_2:taxCode>9014</v1_2:taxCode>
        <v1_2:installmentNumber>1</v1_2:installmentNumber>
        <v1_2:dueDate>2011-02-28</v1_2:dueDate>
        <v1_2:amount>
          <amount>174134.40</amount>
        </v1_2:amount>
        <v1_2:taxShortName>Y.DIŞI ÇKŞ.H</v1_2:taxShortName>
      </v1_2:debtLineItem>
      <v1_2:debtLineItem>
        <v1_2:taxCode>9014</v1_2:taxCode>
        <v1_2:installmentNumber>1</v1_2:installmentNumber>
        <v1_2:dueDate>2011-02-28</v1_2:dueDate>
        <v1_2:amount>
          <amount>174134.40</amount>
        </v1_2:amount>
        <v1_2:taxShortName>Y.DIŞI ÇKŞ.H</v1_2:taxShortName>
      </v1_2:debtLineItem>
    </v1_1:collectionData>
  </v1_1:collect>
  </p:Body>
 </csrequest>
</csprint>
```

and here is my condition:

```
if (mainTaxCode == 9077 && taxCode == 1086)
  sum /debtLineItem/amount/amount of all 1086 nodes and write just once
else
  write all
```

and for this instance the result should look like

```
TaxCode      DueDate      Amount
  1086     2011-02-28    348268.80
  9014     2011-02-28    174134.40
  9014     2011-02-28    174134.40
```

I cannot move on any further, keeps summing all 3 values. Any help appreciated.
Thanks..

Comment: I think it would be better if you provide a bit more complex sample of your input data and change the wanted output accordingly.

Comment: I made the change you suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This transformation outputs the wanted data exactly according to the described condition (I think :P). Moreover conditional values are parametric (default to 9007 and 1086).

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:v1_1="http://isbank.com/OpSvcs/PaymentMgmtProcessing/TaxCollection/Service/V1"
    xmlns:v1_2="http://isbank.com/OpSvcs/PaymentMgmtProcessing/Tax/Schema/V1">

    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:param name="mainTaxCode" select="9077"/>
    <xsl:param name="taxCode" select="1086"/>

    <xsl:key name="k" match="v1_2:debtLineItem" 
        use="v1_2:taxCode"/>

    <xsl:template match="v1_1:collect">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="
            v1_1:collectionData
                [v1_2:mainTaxCode=$mainTaxCode]/
                v1_2:debtLineItem
                    [generate-id() 
                    = generate-id(key('k', v1_2:taxCode)[1])]
                    [v1_2:taxCode=$taxCode]
            |
            v1_1:collectionData/
                v1_2:debtLineItem
                    [not(v1_2:taxCode=$taxCode)]"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="v1_2:debtLineItem">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(
            v1_2:taxCode, ' ', 
            v1_2:dueDate, ' ')"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="v1_2:taxCode[.=$taxCode]" mode="sum"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="v1_2:taxCode[.!=$taxCode]"/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="v1_2:taxCode" mode="sum">
        <xsl:value-of select="
            format-number(sum(key('k',.)/v1_2:amount/*), '#.00')"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="v1_2:taxCode">
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number(../v1_2:amount, '#.00')"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: this is more accurate, thanks a lot. I will improve it obviously :)

Comment: You are welcome. I've updated the answer trying to improve it a bit. Cheers

Comment: ok, one more problem. if mainTaxCode in the xml is not 9077 then 1086 lines not show up. just change 9077 to 9078 and there is no 1086 lines (by the way if it is 9078 there should be two lines of 1086 just like 9014)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right: this template groups by `v1_2:taxCode` and sums `v1_2:amount/amount`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:v1_2="http://isbank.com/OpSvcs/PaymentMgmtProcessing/Tax/Schema/V1">

    <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:key name="k" match="v1_2:debtLineItem" use="v1_2:taxCode"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//v1_2:debtLineItem[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('k', v1_2:taxCode))]"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="v1_2:debtLineItem">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(
                      v1_2:taxCode, ' ', 
                      v1_2:dueDate, ' ', 
                      format-number(sum(//v1_2:debtLineItem[v1_2:taxCode = current()/v1_2:taxCode]/v1_2:amount/*), '#.00'))"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xD;&#xA;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
1086 2011-02-28 348268.80
9014 2011-02-28 174134.40
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. there is one more condition, it should group if taxCode is 1086. I mean if there is one more 9014 in the xml, output should have two 9014 lines.